# Median Filter OpenMP Optimization

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, openmp, median

I am trying to parallelize the median filter using the CImg library. The code seems very simple:

```
void omp_median_filter(CImg<float> & img) {
  CImg<float> copy(img);
  size_t i;
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for (i = 1; i < img.width()-1; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 1; j < img.height()-1; j++) {
      for (size_t k = 0; k < img.spectrum(); k++) {
        img(i, j, k) = getNeighboursMedian(copy, i, j, k);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `getNeighboursMedian` function is irrelevant for this case, but anyway:

```
float getNeighboursMedian(CImg<float> & img, int i, int j, int k) {
  float neighbours[9];
  int kk = 0;
  for (size_t ii = i-1; ii <= i+1; ii++) {
    for (size_t jj = j-1; jj <= j+1; jj++) {
      neighbours[kk++] = img(ii,jj,k);
    }
  }
  sort(&neighbours[0], &neighbours[8]);
  return neighbours[4];
}
```

My question is: is there any extra pragma argument I can use to make it go faster? I've been trying a couple of things but no one increases the algorythm's performance... I got no clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you aren't willing to specify a platform, loop counts, numbers of threads and cores, specific compiler...

Comment: So consider int or int_64t in place of size_t, possible collapse or vectorization, can you persuade your compiler to generate optimization report...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at the code of the CImg method `CImg<T>::blur_median()`. It implements the median filter with openMP parallelization as well. Search for it in file `CImg.h`.